# Connecting game consoles on a 23" Cinema Display?

Tags: display, hdmi, cinema-display

I have an old 23" DVI Apple Cinema Display (from ~2004 I believe) that my dad found awhile back. I bought a DVI to HDMI adapter to use it with my MacBook Pro and it works flawlessly. I can also connect and display my iPad Pro with no problems. I'm moving out for college soon and figured it would be a good monitor to use in my dorm for video games.

I tried hooking up my Nintendo Switch to the display through the same HDMI to DVI connector as my MacBook uses and had no luck. The display knows it has something hooked up to it, because the light on the front of the display blinks, but nothing is outputted to the screen itself. I tried connecting a few other HDMI devices to the display and the same thing happened: the light blinks, but no output.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Do Cinema displays only accept input from Apple devices? Is there a way to work around this or am I just SOL?

Comment: It’s a Nintendo issue.  See:  https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/70648/~/nintendo-switch-will-not-display-to-monitor-via-hdmi-%26gt%3Bdvi-cable-after-4.0/comment/12906